# Он налил ему виски "на два пальца"

Tags: кавычки

Как вы считаете, следует ли брать в кавычки выражение "на два пальца" в следующем предложении?

*Он налил ему виски "на два пальца".*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Здесь - да, лучше закавычить.
Хотя вообще - не обязательно. Выражение нельзя назвать совершенно новым и непонятным. Но вот именно в такой фразе возникает двусмысленность. Не могу объяснить почему. Если просто "налей на два пальца" (клиент - бармену), то никаких побочных ассоциаций не возникает. Субъективно, разумеется.

Answer (score 0):

Это устойчивое словосочетание, в которых кавычки вообще не употребляются.

Во всех примерах из литературы/книг выражение "на два пальца" без кавычек.

Происхождение этого выражения довольно занятное. «Налить на два пальца» берет начало из салунов Дикого Запада (1830 – 1920-е), где бармен отмерял виски, горизонтально прикладывая к стакану два пальца.

Например, если вы привязали лошадь, убрали пистолет в кобуру, зашли в салун и попросили “два пальца виски”, бармен наливал вам неразбавленный виски комнатной температуры на высоту, равную ширине его указательного и среднего пальца.

Поскольку пальцы у всех барменов были разные, то объем получался приблизительный. Потом появились дозаторы, и метод потихоньку стал отмирать. Сейчас некоторые бары пытаются его реанимировать; не исключено, что скоро в барной культуре вновь появится термин “два пальца”.

Пример:
Мне на два пальца вашего самого мягкого виски, бармен!

Источник: [https://www.fluentu.com/blog/english-rus/английский-для-бармена/](https://www.fluentu.com/blog/english-rus/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0/)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99532/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd-------).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова 1. А вот тут интересный момент - специально так написал: выражение, в которых (в таких выражениях - то есть не только в этом, а во всех) - редкий случай согласования по смыслу. 2. Про даты - копировал из источника. 3. Да я вообще не нашёл ни одного примера с *налить "на два пальца"*.